# How can I get 3 different taxonomy type terms in a div class element?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

I have this situation where I need to filter specific post type posts by its taxonomies (there 3 different ones) and since I am using Isotope, I need them in my class element. I already made it work with one and I believe I took the 'long' road. I dont really work that much with php, this is what I could get from codex...

1) I get custom post type entries
2) inside

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'resource_roles' );  
if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 

    $links = array();

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $links[] = $term->name;
    }

    $tax_links = join( " ", str_replace(' ', '-', $links));          
    $tax = strtolower($tax_links);
else :  
    $tax = '';                  
endif; 

echo '<div class="color-shape resource-block ' . $tax . '">';
echo '<h1>' . the_title() . '</h1>';
echo '</div>';
```

As seen in the code, now it ads 'resource_roles' taxonomy elements, now I need to add 'resource_media' and 'resource_theme'. :/
I believe there is shorter way, community, can you help me make this code neat and short?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using get_the_terms, you can just do your if loop once for each taxonomy and then join them after the three loops.

Of course, it would probably be more efficient to use:

```
wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy, $args );
```

You could then do something like:

```
wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, array( 'resource_roles', 'resource_media', 'resource_theme' ) );
```

Which would pull all of the terms in one query.

To echo them into your class attribute, use the code you use when they are all the same type:

```
$extra_classes = '';
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, array('resource_roles','resource_media','resource_theme');
if ( is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
   # Log the error, notify someone, etc.
} else if ( 0 < count( $terms ) ) {
   $slugs = array();
   foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
      $slugs[] = $term->slug;
   }
   $extra_classes = implode(' ', $slugs);
}
$title = get_the_title();
echo <<<HTML
<div class="color-shape resource-block {$extra_classes}">
   <h1>{$title}</h1>
</div>
HTML;
```

Comment: Hi, if i get terms in one query, how can i expose them to echo  into my class attribute?

Comment: updated to show how to put them to use.